# Bash: Escaping list of files

Tags: bash-scripting

Can this be done more nicely (echo a placeholder for another command)

```
echo $(for x in *;do echo $x|sed 's/\([ \t\n\r\v\f\;#]\)/\^\1/g'|sed 's/$/\;/g';done)
```

Also, there should be no ; after the last filename.

example usage of the command 'doit' is

```
doit files[ list-of-files ] 'flags[foo;bar;other^ flag]options[value^ 1[1]value^ array[1;2;3]]'
```

etc.

It is possible to escape whitespace internally (in doit), since it does not affect the doits tokenizer (it just eats every whitespace not following ^). As well as the good extensibility of the syntax, the code for reading configuration files and the command line is the same.

The sed thing works expect that it adds a ; too much at the end. However, logic for adding ; inside doit is not hard to implement so this last step is not nessecary. What I dislike, is that I need a loop to escape each argument individually. Just echo * | sed ... would not do it since echo destroys information (printing everything delimited by whitespace).

Similar problem: I want to add echo ~/my_progs/* colon separated to the path variable.

Comment: Why not just fix the command to handle arguments properly in the first place?

Comment: Can you tell us what you really need to do or why you would need this? Like Ignacio said, this is probably a question of just interpreting the arguments correctly, not forcing them into some format. See also: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem

Comment: Well, the command *requiers* a special format. This format is hierarcical: a level begins with [ and ends with ].

Comment: Hm. It'd probably be easier if you could show us an example list of files and the exact format that this magical `doit` requires. Or is your command working perfectly already and you're just looking for something "nicer", because…?

Comment: As @slhck said, we will need an example of the input and expected output and, preferably, the elusive `doit` to answer you.

Comment: @slhck doit works, but I want it to work well with shell expansion. The reason it does not follow POSIX syntax is that a consistent option-grouping is needed. And, the syntax chosen works well in a configuration file too.

Comment: So please show some concrete example of files and the expected output. Or does your sed thing work fine already? If so, what is the actual question?

Comment: @slhck The sed thing works expect that it adds a ; too much at the end. However, logic for adding ; inside doit is not hard to implement so this last step is not nessecary. What I dislike, is that I need a loop to escape each argument individually. Just ecjp

Comment: If its adding an extra `;` just remove the last `sed` command: `sed 's/$/\;/g'`. You are explicitly telling it to add a `;` at the end. There probably is a nicer way of doing this but we cannot find it unless you give us concrete examples. Up to you.

Comment: @terdon It is mostly the loop I do not like.

Comment: You want to apply a single command to a list of files without using a loop? I don't understand, are you looking for a quantum computing solution? As far as I know, the only way of doing this is a loop, by definition.

Comment: @terdon No, but more shell magic that boils down to a loop.

Comment: I assume setting the **IFS** variable did the trick?

Comment: @justbrowsing IFS does not help. echo is the bad guy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unclear what you are trying to do but based on "escaping list of files" I think this is the solution:

```
IFS=$(echo -en "\n\b");
for file in $list; do
  sed -i 's/before/after/g' "$file";
done;
```

Setting the environmental variable **IFS** (Internal File Separator) to that will correctly separate files based on line breaks.

---

Or possibly, use `find` if you don't want to use a loop.

```
doit() { find -name "$@" -exec sed -i 's/before/after/g' {} \; }
doit myfiles*txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I wanted to do it directly in shell but compiling a C program works better. From the shell view this is a "quantum computer": One op that runs a lot faster than the shell script above. I guess it takes alot more time to spawn sed for each file.

```
#include <cstdio>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
    {
    if(argc==0)
        {return -1;}
    --argc;
    ++argv;
    while(argc)
        {
        const char* arg=*argv;
        while(*arg)
             {
             if(*arg>='\0' && *arg<=' ')
                 {putchar('^');}
             switch(*arg)
                 {
                 case '[':
                 case ']':
                 case ';':
                 case '^':
                 case '#':
                     putchar('^');
                 }
             putchar(*arg);
             ++arg;
             }
         --argc;
         if(argc)
             {putchar(';');}
         ++argv;
         }
    return 0;
    }
```